# An alternative algorithm for blob detection

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, detection

Here's a sample image of my experiment which is to be processed for finding the information of all the blobs (centre, dimension etc.). Basically the image below contains some noise, few bold lines, and of course few blobs.

[image]

My aim is to program an FPGA using an image processing package "Sapera APF". Sapera APF is an application for programming Teledyne DALSA frame grabbers to perform image processing. And unfortunately it doesn't allow us to write code in conventional way, neither allows to use basic coding features (if else statements, loops etc.) but only supports some inbuilt functions in form of code blocks, and we can only arrange these blocks.
FYI, Here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9f5qc9uki0lsalu/sapera_functions.docx) to a list of functions supported by Sapera.

Now, my first objective was to test my algorithm on matlab thereafter implementing it on Sapera. Here is my approach in matlab:

1. Applied mean filter (for step 3)
2. Thresholded image using adaptive thresholding (returning a binary image)
3. Removed lines by checking connectivity, all lines are connected with above 100 pixels      (for better connectivity mean filter was applied first)
4. Now since only blobs were remaining, their location were identified (with `grayvalue=255`) and corresponding pixels were taken in original image.

This is a simple algorithm which works fine in matlab. But the real problem is that for step 3 (i.e. connectivity) of course I had to write loops going to each pixel checking for connectivity, which can't be done in Sapera. So I am looking for some other simpler algorithm to separate blobs in my images, without using loops and conditional statement, so that it can be implemented in Sapera, but now I just need its matlab code or algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, all the Sapera operations belong to the family of point-to-point or neighborhood operations (= image processing), and there is little that can help you segment out the blobs. (Indeed, there is no function that will return "a small number of something"; they all return full images or scalar values.)

As a workaround you can

- limit processing to a region of interest (a vertical stripe sure to contain the blobs - but you can ignore the sides);
- use the horizontalSum function to get an image profile in which you can find the peaks corresponding to the blobs (you'll have to program it yourself, but the amount of data is much reduced);
- similarly, use the verticalSum to find the horizontal limits.

Given the excellent separation of the blobs, that should be enough to delimit bounding boxes for every blob.

As you see on the plot of the vertical profile of your image, peak detection is easy (provided you avoid the lateral lines).

[image]

And the horizontal profile is really seamless.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To conveniently separate lines from pointlike-peaks without many connectivity checks I would:

- Smooth the image data (convolve with gaussian kernel)
- Search for local maxima (larger than circshift in all directions) above a threshold, the data should be smoothed so much before that there is at most one local maximum per object
- Compute local ellipticity at each maximum (see below)
- Only accept local maxima with a low ellipticity

How to compute local ellipticity:

- Compute second central moments on the data (background subtracted), i.e. weighted summing of data around each peak with `x^2`, `y^2` or `xy`, where x and y are coordinates with the origin at the peak position.
- Diagonalize the matrix consisting of [moment_xx, moment_xy; moment_xy, moment_yy] to obtain measures for the lengths of large and short axis of a local elliptic shape.
- Define ellipticity as ratio of the larger to the smaller axis.

In the special case of having only horizontal or vertical but never diagonal lines you also just compute the `x^2` and `y^2` weighted moments and only accept those who are reasonably equal.